# Spring RestTemplate - BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory & SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I saw the below code in one of the Rest Clients built using Spring. This Rest Client is present within a REST service and is calling another REST service. What is the purpose of this statement?

```
return new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory())
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory.html) is a decorator around `ClientHttpRequestFactory`, which the RestTemplate uses to create [`ClientHttpRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequest.html)s which faciliate HTTP communication. This decorator in particular provides buffering of outgoing/incoming streams. This wrapper/decorator also allows multiple reads of the response body, which you won't be able to do if you only use [`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html) or [`HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) without this wrapper.

[`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html) is an implementation of `ClientHttpRequestFactory`, which uses JDK facilities (classes from `java.net` package) and therefore does not depend on third party libraries, such as Apache HttpComponents HTTP client, which is required by another implementation [`HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html).